# Hide PHP errors on Godaddy Wordpress Hosting

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hide (but log) the PHP errors on **GoDaddy Managed Wordpress hosting** but to no avail.

I have tried creating a **php.ini / php5.ini** file but it didn't work.

Can someone comment on a possible solution? I want to keep the solution viable even after WordPress and/or theme is updated.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Dagon ... I guess you missed the *WordPress* bit ;) ... with regards to the question, many PHP ini settings can be set in the script itself, e.g. `ini_set('display_errors', '0');` - which should actually be the default on any live environment anyway.

Comment: for wordpress you can add define('WP_DEBUG',false) in you wp-config file.@Asdil P

Comment: @Dagon thanks for the "FIX THEM" message. A) Wordpress B) Third party plugins C)want to hide but still **(log)** them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide PHP errors on any WordPress portal, It doesn't matter where it hosted Please do the following:

We can control show/hide notifications/errors/warnings from **wp-config.php** file which will be in your application folder.

1. Set WP_DEBUG to FALSE

   define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

or

2. WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY is another companion to WP_DEBUG that controls whether debug messages are shown inside the HTML of pages or not.
   Set that to false

   define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );

Make sure that the following lines of code you've in your **wp-config.php** file.

```
// Disable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

Personally, I'll suggest to use the following configuration which will log all your warnings, notices in a file. You can fix whenever you've time.

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

For more details check [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: Thanks Sampath, I was probably trying to make changes via php.ini but totally ignored the possibility of making changes via this option.